# Access object from another class c++

Tags: c++, function, class, object

I'm slowly learning c++ however whilst developing my program im having trouble trying to access and object Ive created. My object is created on a page called source.cpp with

```
Tilemap background;
```

i have another header file, which in tern calls a function with needs to access 'background', the file is called 'player.cpp', however i cant figure out how to define it. Ive included the header file with the tilemap class but since the object is created elsewhere i don't know how to reference it. Google isn't be my friend today and my searching has brought up nothing.

Comment: Code would help to express the problem here.  Along with exact compiler errors./

Comment: in player.cpp use `extern Tilemap background;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
Tilemap background;
```

written at file scope (i.e. not inside a function block) is a global variable *definition*.  It allocates storage in the global data for a variable called *background*.

If you want to refer to this object from another C++ source file, you need to first *declare* the variable so the compiler knows its type.

```
// In another .cpp file
extern Tilemap background;

void f()
{
    background.something();
}
```

Comment: That simple? You've saved me a lot of head scratching, it makes so much sense yet i've tried everything to get that working for hours, i can greatly improve parts of my code thanks to this simple answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
Tilemap background;
```

placed in a global scope (let's say somewhere at the beginning of your `source.cpp` file) declares a global variable that is accessible only within the same compilation unit by default (in this case probably only within `source.cpp`). In `player.cpp`, compiler doesn't know that variable `background` exists.

One solution could be to put:

```
extern Tilemap background;
```

in your `player.cpp` to let the compiler know that there is global variable of type `Tilemap` defined somewhere else.

However, I find it better idea to ***avoid using global variables of this kind*** and try to "spread" (pass) variables / objects in form of arguments while calling some member functions ("methods"). After all, communication between objects is what OO programming is about... (I would provide some concrete example if I knew the context of this class / if you shared some code...)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you are learning C++ then learn the good practices from the start and avoid C++ pitfalls. Declaring and using C++ global objects that way can lead to very nasty behavior and long debugging sessions because you can't be sure the global object background which is declared at file global scope is initialized and properly constructed when you use it in another file. When you use such an object ,let's call it B, in another global object A in another file you cannot be sure B is initialized before the A and that leads to very nasty bugs or if you are lucky a crash. The solution then: make you object background a local static object i.e. local to a function like so:

```
TileMap& getBackground() {
  static TileMap background; //use of "camel case" for the class name
  return background; //return a reference to it 
}
```

That's it. Anywhere you want to use background just call getBackground(). The first time you call it, background local static will be initialized and good to use.

Some will say that this technique is related to the singleton design pattern but this is not my intent here it is just the proper way to use global objects if you absolutely need to. C++ is a great language especially with the release of C++11 but it has some pitfalls you need need to be aware of. Do yourself a favor: grab a copy of [Effetive C++](http://www.amazon.fr/Effective-Specific-Improve-Programs-Designs/dp/0321334876) it will teach almost everything you need to know to use the language properly

Comment: This kind of lazy initialization is sometimes useful, and it does avoid some problems with static object construction, but it also has its own problems, especially if your program is multithreaded -- it is not threadsafe.

Comment: Still the solution you have provided leads to undefined behavior and is not advisable. Thread safety is another issue and neither of the solutions is good for that matter. Still using globals the way you say is plain wrong. You should not shoot yourself in the foot just because C++ lets you do so.